# Rails 4: Edit/Update Threads, Edit/Update Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Before I begin yes I know I need a edit and update function in the posts and threads controller, but the issue I have is with the forum_post.user details getting lost in the update and the thread duplicating posts after the update, so I removed the code entirely so I can get help solving the problem by posting the controllers themselves.

But you're going to need the routes, before I post it /forum/ is just a fake route to nest the forum_threads/posts in and does not exist outside of it's scope.

Rake Routes output

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                          Controller#Action
            new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                                             devise/sessions#new
                user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                                             devise/sessions#create
        destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                                            devise/sessions#destroy
               user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                                            devise/passwords#create
           new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                                        devise/passwords#new
          edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                                       devise/passwords#edit
                             PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                                            devise/passwords#update
                             PUT    /users/password(.:format)                                            devise/passwords#update
    cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                                              devise/registrations#cancel
           user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                                                     devise/registrations#create
       new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                                             devise/registrations#new
      edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                                                devise/registrations#edit
                             PATCH  /users(.:format)                                                     devise/registrations#update
                             PUT    /users(.:format)                                                     devise/registrations#update
                             DELETE /users(.:format)                                                     devise/registrations#destroy
    forum_thread_forum_posts GET    /forum/forum_threads/:forum_thread_id/forum_posts(.:format)          forum_threads/forum_posts#index
                             POST   /forum/forum_threads/:forum_thread_id/forum_posts(.:format)          forum_threads/forum_posts#create
 new_forum_thread_forum_post GET    /forum/forum_threads/:forum_thread_id/forum_posts/new(.:format)      forum_threads/forum_posts#new
edit_forum_thread_forum_post GET    /forum/forum_threads/:forum_thread_id/forum_posts/:id/edit(.:format) forum_threads/forum_posts#edit
     forum_thread_forum_post GET    /forum/forum_threads/:forum_thread_id/forum_posts/:id(.:format)      forum_threads/forum_posts#show
                             PATCH  /forum/forum_threads/:forum_thread_id/forum_posts/:id(.:format)      forum_threads/forum_posts#update
                             PUT    /forum/forum_threads/:forum_thread_id/forum_posts/:id(.:format)      forum_threads/forum_posts#update
                             DELETE /forum/forum_threads/:forum_thread_id/forum_posts/:id(.:format)      forum_threads/forum_posts#destroy
               forum_threads GET    /forum/forum_threads(.:format)                                       forum_threads#index
                             POST   /forum/forum_threads(.:format)                                       forum_threads#create
            new_forum_thread GET    /forum/forum_threads/new(.:format)                                   forum_threads#new
           edit_forum_thread GET    /forum/forum_threads/:id/edit(.:format)                              forum_threads#edit
                forum_thread GET    /forum/forum_threads/:id(.:format)                                   forum_threads#show
                             PATCH  /forum/forum_threads/:id(.:format)                                   forum_threads#update
                             PUT    /forum/forum_threads/:id(.:format)                                   forum_threads#update
                             DELETE /forum/forum_threads/:id(.:format)                                   forum_threads#destroy
                import_users POST   /users/import(.:format)                                              users#import
                       users GET    /users(.:format)                                                     users#index
                             POST   /users(.:format)                                                     users#create
                    new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                                 users#new
                   edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                                            users#edit
                        user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                                 users#show
                             PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                                                 users#update
                             PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                                 users#update
                             DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                                 users#destroy
                        root GET    /                                                                    forum_threads#index
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
devise_for :users
  scope "/forum" do
        resources :forum_threads do
                resources :forum_posts, module: :forum_threads
        end
  end

  resources :users do
    collection do
      post :import
    end
  end
root 'forum_threads#index'
end
```

Forum Threads Controller

```
class ForumThreadsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_forum_thread, except: [:index, :new, :create]

  def index
    @q = ForumThread.search(params[:q])
    @forum_threads = @q.result(distinct: true)
  end

  def show
    @forum_post = ForumPost.new
  end

  def new
    @forum_thread = ForumThread.new
    @forum_thread.forum_posts.new
  end

  def create
    @forum_thread = current_user.forum_threads.new forum_thread_params
    @forum_thread.forum_posts.first.user_id = current_user.id

    if @forum_thread.save
      redirect_to @forum_thread
    else
      render action: :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @forum_thread.destroy
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

    def set_forum_thread
      @forum_thread = ForumThread.find(params[:id])
    end

    def forum_thread_params
      params.require(:forum_thread).permit(:subject, forum_posts_attributes: [:body])
    end
end
```

Forum Posts Controller

```
class ForumThreads::ForumPostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_forum_thread

  def create
    @forum_post = @forum_thread.forum_posts.new forum_post_params
    @forum_post.user = current_user

    if @forum_post.save
      redirect_to forum_thread_path(@forum_thread, anchor: "forum_post_#{@forum_post.id}"), notice: "Successfully posted!"
    else
      redirect_to @forum_thread, alert: "Unable to save your post"
    end
  end

  private

    def set_forum_thread
      @forum_thread = ForumThread.find(params[:forum_thread_id])
    end

    def forum_post_params
      params.require(:forum_post).permit(:body)
    end
end
```

I know the forum edit path for link_to will be edit_forum_thread_path or just correct me if I'm wrong, but it's the posts edit/delete path I need help with since that controller is nested under forum_threads and using the module forum_threads, I originally figured it would be edit_forum_threads_forum_posts_path but that wasn't it either last time I tried before I removed those functions.

Answer (score 0):

It would be `edit_forum_thread_forum_post_path` based on your `rake routes` output.

Comment: Cool, it's the right path but getting some errors that I need help with working out.  http://pastebin.com/12RUyDuW